# Flexbox square items independent of item count

Tags: html, css

I use some inline styling in the HTML Doc. I would like to achieve a flexbox with n divisions where divs are squared. Within these divs I want to add certain images (here a placeholder)

I was looking up some other threads where there was padding used as a measure to adjust the box "height" since it is calculated upon width. However this solution only expands the current box in height (outlined with the blue border).

Has anyone a tip on how to avoid this?

EDIT: Apparently the padding solution works while using units like vh and vw instead of percentage and as long as I do not insert an image

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 35%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage this, there is a little known trick (tbh I didn't know you could do this) with setting an aspect ratio on divs of unknown/dynamic widths. See [this article](https://mademyday.de/height-equals-width-with-pure-css/).

I ended up adding `position: absolute` for the images to not mess with the height of the divs after applying this 1:1 ratio for your scenario:

```
.box:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;    /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
```

This might be what you are trying to do:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 35%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:before {
    content: "";
    float: left;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you also explain the function of before here? Is it kind of creating another box in the box? I see some examples online where they describe :before with some text but not on containers

Comment: as you may be aware, `:before` is a pseudo element which can be used to apply styles to an element without adding more elements to the DOM. [This article](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) may help clear things up or expand more on what else is possible when using these pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2):

We now have access to [**aspect-ratio**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) in CSS although it is poorly supported at the time of writing.

> The aspect-ratio  CSS property sets a preferred aspect ratio for the box, which will be used in the calculation of auto sizes and some other layout functions.

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 35%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  margin: 2.5%;
  flex: 1;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611817757571-75fe5c08ffd9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80">
  </div>

</div>
```